# How to check internet connection before playing video?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I have created the activity of `exoplayer`, when I click play button from `MainActivity` It should open my exoplayer activity file and play my hls source. Even though there is no mobile data or wifi connection, it is trying to open exoplayer and showing black with controls. How to fix this with some condition. My android project is in kotlin. I am using exoplayer version 2.6.0.

```java
    package com.example.sample

    import android.net.Uri
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.os.Handler
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.WindowManager
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultLoadControl
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.DefaultRenderersFactory
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory

    class playlive : AppCompatActivity() {

        private var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null
        private val handler = Handler()

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlive)

            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            actionBar?.hide()
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

         play()

        }

        private fun play(){
        player = 
        ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(DefaultRenderersFactory(this), 
        DefaultTrackSelector(), DefaultLoadControl())
        val playerView = findViewById<SimpleExoPlayerView>(R.id.player_view)
        val uri = Uri.parse("http://localhost/tv2hls/live.m3u8")

        playerView.player = player

        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "user-agent")
        val mediaSource = HlsMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, handler, null)

        player?.prepare(mediaSource)
        player?.playWhenReady = true
    }

        override fun onStop() {
            super.onStop()
            releasePlayer()
            releaseInstance()
        }

        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            releasePlayer()
            resumePlayer()
        }


        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            releasePlayer()
            releaseInstance()
        }

        private fun releasePlayer(){
            player?.release()
        }

        private fun resumePlayer(){
            play()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Brother, Please check network is available or not before you invoke play()

Comment: Can you please explain how to do it bro, I am newbie

Comment: fun isOnline(context: Context): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected
}

if the above method return true then only call play() from your MainActivity

Answer (score 3):

You can use MutableLiveData from Android Jetpack Components like below. This will help you even if you're connected to WiFi but WiFi doesn't have Internet Connectivity.

```
object Network {

private var mMutableData : MutableLiveData<Boolean>? =null
fun isNetworkAvailableWithInternetAccess(mContext: Context): LiveData<Boolean> {
    mMutableData = MutableLiveData()
    val cm = mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo: NetworkInfo?
    networkInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected) isInternetAvailable()
    return mMutableData!!
}

private var parentJob = Job()
private val coRoutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Main

private fun isInternetAvailable() {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(coRoutineContext)
    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val sock = Socket()
            val socketAddress = InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53)

            sock.connect(socketAddress, 2000) // This will block no more than timeoutMs
            sock.close()

            mMutableData!!.postValue(true)

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            mMutableData!!.postValue(false)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Use:

```
Network.isNetworkAvailableWithInternetAccess(context).observe(this, Observer {
        if (it != null) {
            if (it) {
             //Do your work here
            }else{
            //Network is not available do another work
            }
    })
```

Comment: It's better to close the socket in a finally block rather than in try.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to check for Network avaibility

```
fun isNetwork(): Boolean{
        val connectivityManager = context?.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        // In here we return true if network is not null and Network is connected
        return if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected){
            true
        }

    }
```

Then call this function

```
if(isNetwork()){

  //Do your work here
}
else{

  //Network is not available do another work
}
```

Comment: I am getting  2 errors Unresolved reference conext and type mismatch ( Required Boolean, Found: unit) these errors coming

Comment: please show us how you use it, also change `context` to `this` if you are using `Activity`

Comment: I was unable to add code in comment section. How can I share the code?